# How I can empty values get and set together in java?

Tags: java

I have `get and set class` :

```
public static class Structure{
    private String YOne = null;
    private String YTwo = null;
    public String getYOne() {
        return YOne;
    }
    public void setYOne(String YOne) {
        this.YOne = YOne;
    }
    public String getYTwo() {
        return YTwo;
    }

    public void setYTwo(String YTwo) {
        this.YTwo = YTwo;
    }
}
```

Then I fill that in my `class` :

```
Structure.setYOne("my value");
Structure.setYTwo("my value");
```

How I can empty all of them ?

Notice : I don't like empty that one by one .

Comment: `Structure` is inner class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebuild your object, no other choice if you don't want to do it one by one

```
Structure s = new Structure();
// YOne and YTwo are null

s.setYOne("my value");
s.setYTwo("my value");
// YOne and YTwo are not null;

s = new Structure();
// YOne and YTwo are null again
```

edit : be careful though, it could mess up your reference if your object is used in another class.

Answer (score 5):

You can implement a method in your `Structure` class that sets all the fields to `null` using *Reflection*:

```
public void clearFields() throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field[] properties = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field f : properties) {
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(this, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is setAccessible ?

Comment: Check out the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible(java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject[],%20boolean))

Answer (score 0):

You are lacking basic class and object concept here. You need to create an array of objects of `Structure` class. The use a foor loop to loop through all the objects and set methods.

```
for(Structure x : your_array_of_Structures ){
     x.set(whatever);
     x.get(whatever);

   }
```

Go to http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm where you can get more tutorials on how to do these basic things in Java.